# R dplyr gather wide to long multiple columns multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following wide-form data:

```
identity = c("Race1", "Race2", "Race3")
total_2017 = c(300,325,350)
total_2018 = c(200,225,250)
total_2019 = c(100,150,200)
pct_2017 = total_2017/sum(total_2017[1],total_2018[1],total_2019[1])
pct_2018 = total_2018/sum(total_2017[2],total_2018[2],total_2019[2])
pct_2019 = total_2019/sum(total_2017[3],total_2018[3],total_2019[3])
df.wide <- cbind.data.frame(identity, total_2017, total_2018, total_2019, pct_2017, pct_2018, pct_2019)
```

The wide data looks like this:

```
     identity total_2017 total_2018 total_2019  pct_2017  pct_2018 pct_2019
1    Race1        300        200        100 0.5000000 0.2857143   0.1250
2    Race2        325        225        150 0.5416667 0.3214286   0.1875
3    Race3        350        250        200 0.5833333 0.3571429   0.2500
```

The 3rd, 4th and 5th columns are the totals of "identity" for years 2017 to 2019, and the last three columns are the respective shares. 
I want to convert it into long format such that the `totals` are gathered into a column `Enrollment` and the percentages are gathered into a column `Percent`. I try  the following code:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(magrittr)
    library(tidyr)

df.long <- df.wide %>% 
  gather(key = "Total", value = "Enrollment", starts_with("total_")) %>%
  gather(key = "Share", value = "Percent", starts_with("pct_"))
```

Here are the first 10 rows of the long form data.

```
    head(df.long, 10)
   identity      Total Enrollment    Share   Percent
1     Race1 total_2017        300 pct_2017 0.5000000
2     Race2 total_2017        325 pct_2017 0.5416667
3     Race3 total_2017        350 pct_2017 0.5833333
4     Race1 total_2018        200 pct_2017 0.5000000
5     Race2 total_2018        225 pct_2017 0.5416667
6     Race3 total_2018        250 pct_2017 0.5833333
7     Race1 total_2019        100 pct_2017 0.5000000
8     Race2 total_2019        150 pct_2017 0.5416667
9     Race3 total_2019        200 pct_2017 0.5833333
10    Race1 total_2017        300 pct_2018 0.2857143
```

As can be seen, the Enrollment and Percent are ordered differently. How to have the same order in the columns?

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: I want the Percent column to follow the order in the Total (2017, 2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `pivot_longer` which can reshape multiple sets of columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df.wide %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -identity, names_to = c('.value', 'year'), 
         names_sep="_") %>%
   arrange(year)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  identity year  total   pct
#  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Race1    2017    300 0.5  
#2 Race2    2017    325 0.542
#3 Race3    2017    350 0.583
#4 Race1    2018    200 0.286
#5 Race2    2018    225 0.321
#6 Race3    2018    250 0.357
#7 Race1    2019    100 0.125
#8 Race2    2019    150 0.188
#9 Race3    2019    200 0.25
```

Comment: in base R `reshape(df.wide,matrix(names(df.wide)[-1],2,byrow = T),dir="long")`. I was curious why he had too many rows But I guess he was not correct

Comment: Just wondering how to specify ```names_sep``` if there were no "separators" in the column name. For example, these are the names of four columns g1, g2, anon1, anon2.

Comment: @PrasannaS you can have `names_sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])"`

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Where to find these finer details? Are these from the stringr library?

Comment: @PrasannaS it is a regex lookaround which is. unrelated to the package i..e any regex lookaround should work in the `names_sep`.  It implies the boundary between a letter and a digit

Comment: @PrasannaS for more details, you can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)